# Istio outboundTrafficPolicy for pods in and out of the service mesh

Tags: kubernetes, istio, servicemesh

I'm Trying to understand how Istio envoy proxy works when `outboundTrafficPolicy` mode is set to REGISTRY_ONLY.  With the setup defined below I would expect that the `inside` pod would be blocked from accessing the `outside` pod since the `sidecar.istio.inject` label is set to `"false"` for the  outside pod and `"true"` for the inside pod.  However when I exec into the `inside` pod and issue a curl command I get a success .

```
kubectl -n istio-test exec -it inside-85f794ff76-7x44s -c sleep -- curl  http://outside
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

Configuration Setup

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: outside
  name: outside
  namespace: istio-test
spec:
  ports:
  - name: 80-80
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: outside
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: inside
  name: inside
  namespace: istio-test
spec:
  ports:
  - name: 80-80
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: inside
  clusterIP: None
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: outside
  name: outside
  namespace: istio-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: outside
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: outside
        version: v1
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: httpd
        name: httpd
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: inside
  name: inside
  namespace: istio-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: inside
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: inside
        version: v1
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: curlimages/curl
        name: sleep
        command:
        - /bin/sleep
        - infinity
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Sidecar
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: istio-test
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: inside
  outboundTrafficPolicy:
    mode: REGISTRY_ONLY
```

I was expecting to need a `ServiceEntry` to register the external pod.  Why does this not appear to be the case?

How can I block traffic from the `inside` pod to the `outside` pod?

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  Posed in ServerFault
https://serverfault.com/questions/1150892/istio-outboundtrafficpolicy-for-pods-in-and-out-of-the-service-mesh

Answer (score 1):

Istio "REGISTRY_ONLY" option blocks the traffic when there is no HTTP service or service entry defined within the mesh.  In above case there is service "outside" which is getting created.  To understand "REGISTRY_ONLY" option, the example explained [istio document](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/#envoy-passthrough-to-external-services) can be evaluated.

The option to block the traffic for "outside" service application is to use "Authorization Policy".

Below is one the sample to deny all traffic.  More options on authorization policy are explained in [istio document](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/)

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-nothing
  namespace: istio-test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: outside
```

Comment: I see the documentation you are referring to here
`Authorization Policy scope (target) is determined by “metadata/namespace” and an optional selector.
“metadata/namespace” tells which namespace the policy applies. If set to root namespace, the policy applies to all namespaces in a mesh.
workload selector can be used to further restrict where a policy applies.`
However when I apply the authpolicy to`app: outside` it does not seem to work.  Is this because outside does not have a sidecar to apply the policy against?

Comment: Applying a Sidecar config to deny the outgoing request from inside however did work.